# GRE IP to virtual machine (Proxmox) - Traceroute showing full route

Tags: networking, routing, nat, tunneling, proxmox

`88.198.49.xxx` = Hetzner (will run virtual machines on this)

`141.94.176.xxx` = OVH (contains block below)

`164.132.xxx.0/28` = IP block to use on Hetzner as virtual machines

To get GRE set up I ran the following:

OVH:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 88.198.49.xxx local 141.94.176.xxx ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip route add 164.132.xxx.0/28 dev gre1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Hetzner:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 141.94.176.xxx local 88.198.49.xxx ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip rule add from 164.132.xxx.0/28 table 666
ip route add default dev gre1 table 666
ip route add 164.132.xxx.0/28 dev vmbr0 table 666
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

/etc/network/interfaces (Hetzner)

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 164.132.xxx.1/28
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

When I traceroute 164.132.xxx.1 it works great doesn't show Hetzner IP

```
  7     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.95.34.50
  8     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.73.1.135
  9     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.72.66.67
 10     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.164.42.155
 11     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  xxxxxx [141.94.176.xxx]
 12    17 ms    17 ms    17 ms  xxxxxx [164.132.xxx.1]
```

However when I traceroute the virtual machine using 164.132.xxx.2 I get the following result

```
  7     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.95.34.32
  8     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.73.1.45
  9     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.72.66.67
 10     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  10.164.42.163
 11     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  xxxxxx [141.94.176.xxx]
 12    14 ms    14 ms    14 ms  xxxxxx [88.198.49.xxx]
 13    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  xxxxxx [164.132.xxx.2]
```

How can I hide it so that 88.198.49.xxx is not shown? I believe this can be done with NAT but I do not want to use a NAT address as the virtual machines address. I want to keep the config as it is below for virtual machines if possible.

```
IP: 164.132.xxx.2/28
Gateway: 164.132.xxx.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP addresses 88.198.49.xxx and 164.132.xxx.1 represent the same system: the hypervisor acting as router at Hetzner.

So when the target is this system itself, it will answer back with the address it was contacted with: 164.132.xxx.1. When it's acting as a router for 164.132.xxx.2, it will generate an ICMP *TTL expired in transit* and will select the most appropriate address from its routing table. It would have chosen by default the primary IP address on the involved interface (`gre1`) but as this interface has no IP address set, it will follow some algorithm and get instead 88.198.49.xxx (maybe because it's the local tunnel endpoint address? Doesn't matter).

Normally to change this behavior, one hints the route with an `src` parameter, as [documented](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8.en.html#src):

> `src`*`ADDRESS`*
>
> the source address to prefer when sending to the destinations covered
> by the route prefix.

So replacing the default route in table 666 from:

> ```
> ip route add default dev gre1 table 666
> ```

to:

```
ip route add default dev gre1 src 164.132.xxx.1 table 666
```

would work ... except table 666 won't be used when *emitting* a packet. Adding `ip rule iif gre1 table 666` won't be used either to *emit*, nor `ip rule add oif gre1 table 666` which is used to emit when *binding to an interface*.

So this would require a global behavior in the main routing table, but this could lead to issues at Hetzner when an IP address belonging to OVH is leaked and detected. Not good either.

The easiest I could find instead is to mark packets arriving through *gre1* and, to avoid using any heavy *conntrack* feature, use instead the global [`fwmark_reflect`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n70) sysctl toggle:

> `fwmark_reflect - BOOLEAN`
>
> Controls the fwmark of **kernel-generated IPv4 reply packets** that are
> not associated with a socket for example, TCP RSTs or ICMP echo
> replies). If unset, these packets have a fwmark of zero. If set, they
> have the fwmark of the packet they are replying to.

As this event still happens at the routing decision step, the mark has to be set before routing happens.

So in addition to the `src 164.132.xxx.1` change above, also do:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -j MARK --set-mark 666
ip rule add fwmark 666 lookup 666
sysctl -w net.ipv4.fwmark_reflect=1
```

The Hetzner IP address won't be leaked anymore.

Comment: Thanks working but there appears to be an issue? It's showing the route twice

 "11     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  xxxxxx [141.94.176.xxx]
 12    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  xxxxxx [164.132.xxx.2]
 13     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  xxxxxx [141.94.176.xxx]
 14    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  xxxxxx [164.132.xxx.2]"

Comment: To add to my last comment this only appears to be happening with DDoS protected IPs I received from my provider I believe they use path.net DDoS protection service. Will this cause issues?

Comment: Your initial example had 13 steps your new example has 15 steps. Were these 2 additional steps appearing because of the changes I proposed?

Comment: Just in case, there was an unneeded change introduced by `ip rule add fwmark 666 lookup 666` which makes incoming traffic from gre1 use table 666 while this wasn't the case initially. It can be changed to `ip rule add iif lo fwmark 666 lookup 666` to really affect only the kernel reply (but normally gre1 would have interest to use table 666 too).

Comment: Do I need to add anything in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables ?

Comment: You don't need.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help. The double hop at the end still persists but with another provider only that uses path.net DDoS protection so I will just leave it for now OVH > Hetzner is working flawlessly from what I can test.